# Powershell: Azure Web App - Set httpsOnly on

Tags: powershell, azure, https, azure-web-app-service

I'm automating the deployment of an Azure Web App via powershell.  I can't figure out how you force "HTTPS Only" to on.  The code below is my best guess, but it isn't working.  Any ideas?

```
$properties = @{"httpsOnly" = $true}
Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $properties -ResourceGroupName 
$resourcegroupname  -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName 
$webappname/web -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

Comment: Hmm, that ApiVersion is a bit vintage, did you try with `2016-08-01`? I'd also pass `-Debug` to see the request that gets sent on the wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following script.

```
$app=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/shuiapp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/shuicli"
$app.Properties.httpsOnly=$true
$app|Set-AzureRmResource -Force
```

Note: If you want to set `httpsOnly on`, the web app's App Service plan must be a paid tier (Shared, Basic, Standard, or Premium). More information about this please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#prerequisites).

I also test in Visual Studio, it also works for me.

[image]

I suggest you could upgrade your Azure Power Shell version.

Comment: For a know [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1228#issuecomment-347861312) on Github, after you execute the script, you need refresh your browser, then you could see this change.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply.  I'm getting the following error:   [ERROR] The property 'httpsOnly' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the 
[ERROR] property exists and can be set.   Note, I am executing this from visualstudio.

Comment: @B.Tullero It seems you use a older version Power Shell, I suggest you could upgrade it. See this link https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases

Comment: @B.Tullero I also test in Visual Studio, it also works for me. What version you use? `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` to get the version.